# Order in the presentation

Tags: beamer, matrices

I am giving a presentation and I would like to make the slides in the following order:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The commands are:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand\myarrow{%
  \tikz\draw[red,dashed,thick,-Triangle] (0,0) -- ++(0,-1.1);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\begin{array}{cccccc}
 & f(x) & = & \sqrt{x^2 + 500^2} \cdot 640,00 & + &  (2000 - x) \cdot 312,00\\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  \\
   &  &  & \myarrow &  & \myarrow \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\Rightarrow & f'(x) & = & 640,00\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2 + 500^2}}2x & + & 312,00(-1) 
\end{array} $
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I know the `\pause` command, but I don't think it works in this case, because the second arrow is before the text that needs to appear on the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\onslide`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand\myarrow{%
  \tikz\draw[red,dashed,thick,-Triangle] (0,0) -- ++(0,-1.1);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

$\begin{array}{cccccc}
 & \onslide<1->{f(x) & = & \sqrt{x^2 + 500^2} \cdot 640,00 & + &  (2000 - x) \cdot 312,00\\}
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
   &  &  & \onslide<2->{\myarrow} &  & \onslide<3->{\myarrow} \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\onslide<2->{\Rightarrow & f'(x) & = & 640,00\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2 + 500^2}}2x} & \onslide<3->{+ & 312,00(-1) }
\end{array} $
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.